# Not understanding NavigatorIOS React Naitive

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native

So My app is pretty basic:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Landing from './App/pages/landing.js';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  NavigatorIOS
} from 'react-native';

class twitterQue extends Component {

  _enter() {
    console.log('Hey Girl');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          component: Landing,
          title: 'Welcome!',
          passProps: {},
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('twitterQue', () => twitterQue);
```

I then have a landing component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '../components/button/buttons.js';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

class Landing extends Component {

  _enter() {
    console.log('Hey Girl');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Twitter Que
        </Text>
        <Button type={"primary"} buttonWidth={240} onPress={() => this._enter()}>Que Up Some Tweets!</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Landing', () => Landing);

module.exports = Landing;
```

Nothing to funky. Nothing renders out to the page and there are no errors. The app loads and I see "Welcome!" As the title but the (`Landing`) component doesn't show. **Am I missing something?**

If I move every thing from Landing `render` into index.js `render` it works. Am I misunderstanding the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `style={{flex:1}}` to NavigatorIOS:

```
<NavigatorIOS
    style={{flex:1}}
    initialRoute={{
      component: Landing,
      title: 'Welcome!',
      passProps: {},
    }}
  />
```

NavigatorIOS has no default styling out of the box. So basically there is no default width or height specified. This means that if you do not specify a width and a height, or a flex value, then it will not show up in your view.

Comment: That worked, but can you update your answer to suggest why it work?

Comment: Hey, glad that worked. I've updated the answer to give a better explanation.